# Connect to Windows Azure Database using Smartfox API

Tags: mysql, azure, connection-string, smartfoxserver

I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL database through the Smartfox API.

I open the administration panel, click on the zone configurator module, double click on my zone and click on database manager.

It asks and I supply:

```
Database Driver Class: {SQL Server Native Client 10.0}; //Not sure about this got it from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/
Connection String: Database=databaseName;Data Source=us-cdbr-azure-central-a.cloudapp.net;User Id=userId;Password=password //I get from the Azure portal under settings->properties
Username: userId
Password: password
```

This is not connecting. Is Azure supported by Smartfox?

Actually it's probably because I don't have the right adapter. Is this the right one? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434 Where do I put this in the smartfox directory?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to connect to Azure SQL using a JDBC driver. Kindly try putting the .jar file into **{SFS2XRoot}/lib/** folder.

The required drivers and the steps for the JDBC usage with Azure SQL can be found in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple-windows/).

Also I found [this tutorial](http://smartfoxserver.com/blog/?p=58) on smartfox website, might be helpful.

Hope this helps!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple-windows/

http://smartfoxserver.com/blog/?p=58

Comment: My smartfox is already set up for JDBC. There must be something wrong with my connection string.

Comment: 1) Have you put the driver under the lib folder?
2) Below is a conn string sample for your reference

             String connectionString =
            "jdbc:sqlserver://your_server.database.windows.net:1433;" 
            + "database=your_database;"
            + "user=your_user@your_server;"
            + "password=your_password;"
            + "encrypt=true;"
            + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
            + "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;"
            + "loginTimeout=30;";

Comment: yes, but I cannot enter an entire connection string into smartfox. I must enter it in the format shown in the question